# Subscribing to RESTful API and getting notifications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, backend

I'm having trouble receiving notification from API in JSON format. I've made a SpringBoot application that gets entities from the URL from the server (port:1026). However, the API has a subscription and notification system that I am supposed to utilize.
I'm having trouble realizing the implementation of getting the notification from API. When I subscribe to API a JSON entity is sent that I'm subscribing to I send an endpoint URL (localhost on port:1028) on which the notification is being sent. (entity and endpoint are in the same POST request to API to subscribe).
The issue is I don't know how to listen to that notification and show it on a webpage so when a call is made on API for value of that entity to change I see the notification on server log and see it in real time on my browser webpage.

This is the code that needs to be reworked. Here I just get a GET call from API to see what entities are created but when I make a PUT/POST to API via postman, manual refreshing is needed in order to see the change, and it's not utilizing the subscription system.
I think I need some kind of GET listener from server (localhost:1026) in order to parse the entity.

```
try {
            
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:1026/v2/entities");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            //Check if connection is made
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            // 200 OK
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " + responseCode);
            } else {
                informationString = new StringBuilder();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
                    logger.info("Entity updated");
                }
                //Close the scanner
                scanner.close();
            
                logger.info(String.valueOf(informationString));
                //return String.valueOf(informationString);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return String.valueOf(informationString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) on the webpage to periodically call your API then display the response immediately

Comment: I need  a notification only and only when an entity is created or changed. That's when API sends the Entity in JSON to endpoint defined in subscription.

Comment: have you look at `serviceWorker`? maybe it can help you. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers